# How to design a sawtooth wave generator? (Required specification of sawtooth wave 0-14V and 50kHz)

Tags: circuit-design, analog, sawtooth-waveform

I tried using ICs like the ICL-8038 and the 555 time. It didn't work out because of the supply voltage constraint. I also tried using an op-amp (LTC6244) based circuit. It gave a distorted wave at 50kHz.

I'm new to analogue circuit design. It would be helpful if you could suggest suitable models/ICs for this.

[image: Sawtooth generator using OP-AMPS]

Sawtooth generator using op-amps

[image: Sawooth waveform output]

Sawtooth waveform output

Comment: Instead of immediately jumping to another circuit because a circuit "isn't good enough" have you asked yourself if and what could be done about the issue? The ICL8038 is fine to generate a sawtooth, consider using an **amplifier** to get to the voltage that you need. That aplifier can be an opamp and a couple of resistors. The NE555 isn't a proper sawtooth generator at all. Opamps can be used as well **but you have to use them in a proper circuit**. The best opamp is useless if used in the wrong way / in the wrong circuit.

Comment: I suggest that you study some existing designs and figure out how they work. In Google search for "sawtooth circuit" and press the images tabm you will see plenty of circuits. There should be no need to design your own (do that when you have learned more). Jumping from circuit to circuit will waste your time and only get you confused as you are not going to learn **how** circuits work that way.

Comment: Where is V(n005)?

Comment: V1 and V2 ... Too low. But too high ... +/- 5.25 V max for LTC6244HV ? No decoupling in simulator. Don't forget.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's obvious that n005 is the junction of C2 and D1. It's the only node that could have that waveform and voltage range. But the OP should definitely have indicated this, rather than making us work it out. There's no better way to discourage good answers than by forcing the volunteers here to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distortion of the peaks is due to the fact that you're driving the opamps to their rails. The LTC6244 is a rail-to-rail opamp, but you're asking it to do it at an output current of 7 V / 500 Ω = 14 mA! (Note that **both** opamps need to supply this current, which is flowing through C1.) Take another look at the datasheet to see why this doesn't work.

You need to increase the supply voltages<sup>1</sup> to give the opamps a bit of headroom, and make R1 slightly smaller than R2 to control the actual output swing of U1.

---

<sup>1</sup> This will work in simulation, but when you actually build the circuit, you'll have to pick a different opamp that can actually handle the voltage you're using!